# Foreign variables display as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, class, object

Hello to anyone who will read this post,

I have two standalone javascript files, one of which possesses a class with variables that I would like to use in the other file. We will call the file that possesses the class script.js, and the other file index.js. The code inside index (which is the main file we want to run) compiles fine, but when I run it, my variable prints out as 'undefined'. The variables work fine when they are inside index file themselves, but inside the script.js's class, they are undefined. I would very much like to keep script.js, and keep my variables inside the class. I use an object instance that we will call script obj, and I would very much like to keep my objects. I am not a fan of the static method.

Example: Script.js's class

```js
class script{
constructor(){

var laggies = parseInt(1)
 }
}
```

Above, laggies is defined with a value of 1. Nice, yes? Now let us look at index.js(Just pretend that the object has been initialized)
Example:

```js
console.log(obj.laggies)
```

This is where I get my problem. I am using repl.it with node version 12.16.1

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Defined variable as a local var, it is not on the class instance. Declare it in class and then use `this` to assign value to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the undefined error because the class does not have a variable called laggies. Its defined inside the constructor of the class and not elsewhere.
Try this

```
class script{
 constructor() {
  this.laggies = parseInt( 1)
} 
}
```